# C: f>0 vs Perl: $f>0?

Tags: c, perl

This C code displays Fibonacci numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   for (long long int t, i=1, p=1, f=2; f>0 ; i++, t=f, f+=p, p=t)
      printf("%lli: %lli\n", i, f); 
   }
```

As intended it stops without having to hard code the number of iterations.

The code in Perl is attempting to use the same technique:

```
my $t;
my $p=1;
my $f=2;
for ($i=1; $f>0; $t=$f, $f+=$p, $p=$t, $i++){
   printf("%i: %i\n", $i, $f);
   if ($i>50){exit;}
   }
```

But it does not stop as expected, at the point the value overflows at 45 rather than at
51 when the extra check kicks in.

```
44: 1836311903
45: -1323752223
46: -1
47: -1
48: -1
49: -1
50: -1
51: -1
```

What does Perl do differently that causes this?

Comment: What do you mean "as expected"?

Comment: @Matteo I thought did a quick google to check the spelling but got distracted.

Comment: @khachik added "at the point the value overflows at 45 rather than at 51 when the extra check kicks in".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl uses arbitrary types, switching between unsigned and signed integers and floating point as needed.  printf, however, is forcibly converting the arbitrary type to an integer. Try using %s instead:

```
my $t;
my $p=1;
my $f=2;
for ($i=1; $f>0; $t=$f, $f+=$p, $p=$t, $i++){
   printf("%i: %s\n", $i, $f);
   if ($i>50){exit;}
}
```

The large negative number is in fact stored in perl as an unsigned integer; the -1's are too large floating point numbers being truncated  to the maximum unsigned integer but then treated as signed by %i.

Comment: So, the confusion is on the coder's part that the $f in $f>0 is treated as an integer just because the $f is able to be printed as an integer is because it is an integer rather than it is automagicly converted from some other data type.

Comment: I had trouble parsing that, sorry.  The confusion I think is that perl will use non-integer data types, in effect giving you integers up to 2**53, but printf's integer formats aren't as flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Your C signed integer code overflows from a large number to a negative number and stops. Perl's use of floating pt math lets it go through more iterations with reduced precision, and I don't think it'll wrap around when the number gets really big.

Answer (score 2):

Your `c` code is actually exiting because of poor programming practice. You're relying on `f` being a `long long int`, which has an upper limit of 9.22337204 × 10^18. When you loop around to the 91st iteration `f` becomes 1.22001604 × 10^19, which overflows and becomes negative.

The Perl code continues on merrily but, as you should notice, eventually you'll print out a sequence of `-1`s, which should be a clue that your code is incorrect.

If you didn't have any limits on integer size your `c` code would go on forever, which is probably not what you want. For infinite sequences like the Fibonacci sequence you want to have a halting condition.

Comment: Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/terminating-a-c-loop-when-maximum-hardware-limit-reached

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the Perl code defaults to floating-point arithmetic.  That seems to be what [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Integer-Arithmetic) indicates.  Try throwing a `use integer;` in there.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 32-bit integers in Perl and larger integers in C. 32-bits are not enough to store those numbers. You could rebuild your Perl to use 64-bit integers, or you could let Perl use floating pointer numbers (53-bit integers with no loss) as ysth suggested.